# How to write logs that one can read in mac

Tags: ios, release

I have an iphone release build and i want to write some logs that can be read from mac system .. possibly through iphone logs via terminal or xcode .

Logs that we write gets hidden in reelase mode

Has anybody doen this before ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only can get crash reports of your released app. But there is no way to get other logs to XCode or terminal.

But, You can use third party tools like [crashlytics](https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics) or [Flurry](https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/analytics/gettingstarted/ios/). By which you can create manual logs, that you can receive by mail.